# Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix> Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]

Tags: django, macos, python-2.7, pip

I'm really new to Python and Django.... What I'm trying to do is:

1. Install Python 2.7 on Mac OS 10.6.8
2. Install pip Install Django
3. Install virtualenvwrapper
4. Create virtual environment
5. Install Django-Cms

I think, I'll be is ok from Install virtualenvwrapper to the Django-Cms installation because I have already done it, but in the first steps I got some troubles.

I download `Python 2.z` from python.org the **Python 2.7.3 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer** (for Mac OS X 10.6 and later [2]), installed whit the wizard . That create a directory `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions` with inside my `2.7` folder.

My directory `/System/Library/Python` is empty

I'm sure I've Python installed cos:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.3
```

but when I try `easy_install pip` it gave me:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
'import site' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install-2.6", line 7, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sys, os, zipimport, time, re, imp, new
ImportError: No module named os**
```

Now no idea of what does mean ...so if somebody could help out from this and put me on the direction where I can istall my virtualenvwrapper I can take it from there.

I'm Junior a front end developer never touch back end so pls be specific and explain me what I need to do as u speak with a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have things turned around.  Virtualenv creates a python environment that encapsulates a python install.  So you want to do the following:

1. Install python
2. Create a virtualenv using *that* version of python (eg. virtualenv --python="path to python in 1" *virt*)
3. Switch to that virtualenv (workon *virt*)
4. Now install Django, etc. inside of the virtualenv *virt*

[Here is the recipe](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105151640/http://www.tlswebsolutions.com:80/mac-os-x-lion-setting-up-django-pip-virtualenv-and-homebrew/) I used to get my environment setup and running.

Are you using [homebrew](https://brew.sh)?   I've found that's the most reliable way to get stuff on the mac.

Comment: ok Install homebrew now....so it s possible to create a virtual env whitout install the virtualwrapper ?

Comment: I reckon I have python installed ...I think the path is System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions but I'm not even sure ...sorry ...what I need to do next to create a virtualenv ?

Comment: Hey Alex, follow the recipe in the link http://www.tlswebsolutions.com/mac-os-x-lion-setting-up-django-pip-virtualenv-and-homebrew/ it steps you through all of that.

Comment: ok going now though the "receipt" just put -  brew install python --universal --framework 
and it give me Error: python dependency sqlite not installed with:
  --universal

Comment: The recipe file no longer exists on github.